# Appengine deployment checking for success not working

Tags: google-app-engine

App engine (python 2.7, Mac OS X, latest version as of today) deployment seems to go fine (compilation completed) but deployment is stuck repeating "Will check again in 60 seconds" every 60 seconds until it finally fails, saying :

```
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2025, in Commit
    raise Exception('Version not ready.')
Exception: Version not ready.
```

I've checked appengine status on code.google.com and nothing seems to go wrong.

Any idea if rollback is compulsory ? I had the same problem a couple of hours ago, but after a couple of tries it worked. This time it seems more serious, as i've been stuck in that state for a couple a hours now. Any advice ?

Comment: This kind of question should be posted on the mailing list - it's not an error over which we have any control.

Comment: @mjibson : sorry, i'm not really familiar with the way appengine support works. Didn't know some part of the support was made here on stackoverflow, and some other on the mailing list.

Comment: Don't worry, it's more a problem that support is split between technical issues (stackoverflow) and support/production issues (mailing lists), and this is not easily teachable to the public. This is a known problem, but not easy to solve.

Comment: @mjibson: I guess a "support" button directly on the appengine dashboard website saying "Production issue ? go there . Technical issue ? go there" would do the trick. That's one of the main places you'd expect to see pointers to how support works (apart from the dev tools where the error is triggered, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, these types of issues are best served on the mailing list or issue tracker. However, for the particular issue you mentioned, a [production issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7861) was filed and resolved. You shouldn't be seeing this issue any longer.